# Password Authentication in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the code below

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function checkPswd() {
                var confirmPassword = "Password";
                var password = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
                if (password == confirmPassword) {
                     window.location="www.mywebsite.com";
                }
                else{
                    alert("Incorrect Password For This Account.");
                }
            }
        </script>
```

However I would like to add another password (for two clients) is this possible. I have tried and keep failing.
I need to have two of these  var confirmPassword = "**Password**";

Comment: failing because var password didn't get "pswd" value.. check it by console.

Comment: Are you aware that this is not safe at all? Anyone could just view the page source and see the password. (Or even manually redirect to the page shown there.)

Comment: **Never** store passwords in plaintext inside your backend or frontend. And never send plaintext passwords. Send passwords via SSH over SSL/TLS. Store your passwords on the server - salted with a strong encription.

Comment: This is because it is in testing mode. I am looking for a way but cannot find any. Any advice? I use firebase hosting

Comment: Even in testing mode it adds nothing. My advice would be to implement proper authentication and authorization. If you want to add it later, then just remove this piece and manually go to whatever you assign to `window.location`. That being said, if you want to allow multiple passwords, use a [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments to your question, your approach is very far from being optimal and secure.
However, as for your question the implementation is the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkPswd() {
            var confirmPassword = "Password";
            var confirmPassword2 = "Password2";
            var password = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
            if (password == confirmPassword || password == confirmPassword2) {
                 window.location="www.mywebsite.com";
            }
            else{
                alert("Incorrect Password For This Account.");
            }
        }
    </script>
```